# Javascript / HTML adding a photo to center position on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, photo

I need to paste a small picture in the center of wherever the mouse is clicked. Do I need to locate the mouse position first and then paste the picture there?

Comment: Correct. You can use the MouseEvent data (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp) to retrieve the cursor location ; and then position your picture with CSS using this data. Remember to apply `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` on the image as well, so that the image position is relative to the page instead of being embedded in its HTML parent

Comment: NO! not correct.  You just need to identify the element you clicked on.  Also, suggest you use flex  and js to add image